# Resolve merge conflicts after pull rebase

Tags: git

I'm going through a [tutorial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows) on merging and am stuck on the part where you resolve the conflicts with the remote.

> Then, she’ll edit the file(s) to her liking. Once she’s happy with the
>   result, she can stage the file(s) in the usual fashion and let git
>   rebase do the rest:

and this

> The --rebase option tells Git to move all of Mary’s commits to the tip
>   of the master branch after synchronising it with the changes from the
>   central repository, as shown below:

If I understand correctly I have to get all the remote commits and 'sync' them with my local commits? When the tutorial says sync does it refer to some command of GIT or does it mean I review the each remote commit and decide for myself if any edits need to be made or not before pushing local commits to the front of the master/central stream?

**Update:** I've tried to `git rebase --continue` after leaving a file unchanged but the conflict persists and it won't let me push the commit.

```
> git rebase --continue
Applying: local change since master updated, divergence
Applying: from new local repo
error: Failed to merge in the changes.
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M       services/test.ts
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging services/test.ts
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in services/test.ts
Patch failed at 0002 from new local repo
The copy of the patch that failed is found in: .git/rebase-apply/patch

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".
```

Do I have to use `git rebase --skip` if I want to push a commit without making any changes?

Comment: When a conflict occurs, you need to modify the conflicted files. Run `git status` to find out all the conflicted files. Edit them, remove the unwanted code(including the conflict mark lines like <<<<, ====, and >>>>>) and keep the wanted. When all conflicts are solved, run `git add <conflicted files>` and then `git rebase --continue`.

Comment: what if there is no unwanted code and I dont want to modify the code?

Comment: then just skip the edit. Run `git add` and `git rebase --continue`. But when a rebase is interrupted due to conflicts, there are always conflict marks in the related files. These marks should be removed.

Comment: @el_pup_le, the file contains both version, marked with textual marks. So if you leave it as is it would in practically any case be corrupted for the purpose it should serve. You have to edit the file before running `git add`. See simple instructions in [github help](https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-using-the-command-line/#competing-line-change-merge-conflicts), for example.